# Cookie not accepted while web-scraping with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, post, cookies, web-scraping

I'm making a script to web-scrape from a response to a POST request in a form. The thing is that the page asks for a cookie with a JSESSIONID on it, so before that, the script makes a GET request to the same page to rescue the cookie sent to use it in the POST request, but the page response is 'Error 400: Invalid path /SalidaAplicacion was requested'

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
request = request.defaults({
    jar: true
});

var url = "http://civil.poderjudicial.cl/CIVILPORWEB/AtPublicoDAction.do";
var headers = {
    'Host': 'civil.poderjudicial.cl',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
var options = {
    url: url,
    followredirect: true,
    forever: true,
    headers: headers
}
var form = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': '326',
    'TIP_Consulta': '3',
    'TIP_Lengueta': 'tdDos',
    'SeleccionL': '0',
    'RUC_Tribunal': '3',
    'FEC_Desde': '01/1/2016',
    'FEC_Hasta': '01/2/2016',
    'SEL_Litigantes': '0',
    'COD_Tribunal': '375',
    'irAccionAtPublico': 'Consulta',
    'cpMonth': '1',
    'cpYear': '2016'
}
var cookie;

async.series([
    function getCookie(callback) {
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
            cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'][0];
            callback(null, 1);
        })
    },
    function getPage(callback) {
        headers['cookie'] = cookie;
        request.post({
            url: url,
            form: form,
            headers: headers
        }, function(err,httpResponse,body){
            if (err)
                return console.error('ERROR:', err);
            console.log(body);
            callback(null, 1);
        });
    }]
);
```

Also, when using a cookie from a web browser the page responds in the expected way, so apparently the cookie rescued is not accepted by the page.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you study the network tab in the Chrome debugger when using the browser pages that work and see what is in those requests that you are not sending from your node.js app.  If you simulate what the browser sends exactly, you should be able to get it to work, but you're probably doing something different which the server is objecting to.

Comment: also please note that in the case you use request cookie jar, you shouldn't parse `set-cookie` headers and set them for next operation. Request handles that for you.